# Encrypted UDP (DTLS) in Akka

Tags: encryption, stream, udp, akka, dtls

I need to create a server-clients application in Scala/Akka for encrypted live video streaming. Since loosing some packets doesn't matter, but speed (latency) is crucial, UDP is much better than TCP.

As far as I know Akka/Scala/Java don't support DTLS. What would be the best framework / library to use for encryption?

Also, I am still deciding between different Akka libraries to build the core of the application. (Akka I/O, Akka Remoting, Spray, Akka Http, Akka Streams). Is it worth waiting for a stable release of Akka Streams?

Comment: Not specific to Akka: UDP is not faster than TCP but if you accept packet loss the latency can be lower, which might be important for real-time requirements (e.g. video conferencing). But you have to implement your own flow control to make effective use of the bandwidth (see RTP, RTCP). For one-way streaming where buffering is acceptable TCP might be the easier (and not slower) choice.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, latency is important since the video streaming will be real-time. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: This is the first result on searching for "UDP encryption scala" and it would have been very useful to get peoples experience on having used some system. As it stands it was a waste of time. I suggest that this is reworded and reopened. Maybe a question that will lead to people writing about their experience of different methods.